# How to insert this alert info into a div

Tags: jquery, ajax, weather-api

Hi i have this jQuery ajax code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/10ea0e643a3d7699/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(parsed_json) {
            var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
            var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
            alert("Current temperature in "+location+" is: " + temp_f );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

and i want to show the content of alert into a div in the body like

```
<div id="meteo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the alert function, to make any calls to alert open a custom DIV based popup to provide a consistent popup across browsers with a custom feel for your site.

```
window.alert = function() {
    $('#meteo').html('your content');
    $('#meteo').show();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If the content is text use:

```
$('#meteo').text("Current temperature in "+location+" is: " + temp_f );
```

If your content is html use:

```
$('#meteo').html("<span>Current temperature in "+location+" is: " + temp_f +"</span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the content you want to include in the div is purely text, a good option is:

```
$("#meteo").text("Current temperature in "+location+" is: " + temp_f)
```

If you want to put HTML content inside of the div, this is better:

```
$("#meteo").html("Current temperature in "+location+" is: " + temp_f)
```